# Changing one ListViews style affects other ListViews also

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, controltemplate

I have a WPF ControlTemplate that contains a ListView (Lets call this 'Original ListView') and another custom WPF control that has its own Control Template containing a ListView (Lets call this 'Custom ListView').

I am changing the Original ListViews Style like so:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyClass}}, Path=MyVariable}" Value="0">
        <Setter Property="ListView.ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource itemsPanelTemplate1}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyClass}}, Path=MyVariable}" Value="1">
        <Setter Property="ListView.ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource itemsPanelTemplate2}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style> 

<ListView x:Name="My_ListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MyListViewItemStyle}"/>
```

What I am seeing is that when I change the style for Original ListView by changing MyVariable the Custom ListViews style also changes.

How can I avoid this so that the style change only affects the ListView I want?

Comment: Where is your style defined and how do you set the Style of the "original" ListView?

Comment: The Style I have copied above is defined inside the ControlTemplate that contains the 'original ListView.  I set the style by changing the MyVariable and the DataTriggrers apply either itemsPanelTemplate1 or itemsPanelTemplate2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `Style` doesn't have an `x:Key` attribute, it is applied to all `ListBox` elements that are in scope. This is called implicit data templating.

If you only want to apply the `Style` to a single `ListView`, you should give the `Style` an `x:Key`:

```
<Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}">
```

...and set the `Style` property of the `ListView` to which you want to apply the Style using a `StaticResource`:

```
<ListView x:Name="original" Style="{StaticResource myStyle}" ... />
```